# Jaspersoft Studio - one sorting for multiple subqueries

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am using Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1 with Jasper Report Server Community edition and I have a report with multiple subreports . All subreports have their own SQL queries and they all return the same columns. Once all queries are executed I would like to present all data on my report as one table using a sorting order over the entire dataset (all results from all queries).

It looks to me like I need to sort the data in the report and I cannot find how to do it.

Any ideas/help would be much appreciated - so thank you in advance.

Comment: Each table is a separate component, you can't treat them as one item and you can't perform operations on them as if they are. If you want to aggregate this data into a single table then you will need to do this within the SQL and create a single dataset for a single table.

Comment: maybe  [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) can help you out to create a single query if not you need to go down the java path, create beans (fill from different queries), sort and pass to jasper-reports

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they help a lot.
UNION in SQL is what I do now. Unfortunately:
1) UNION might be quite slow to execute in some cases.
2) UNION is not possible when subsqueries are run of various databases.
Anyway, thank you a lot.